# Add recipients based on user role to failed and cancelled WooCommerce emails

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I want to be able to change who receives the Woocommerce email notifications based on what role the user is when ordering.

For example, If the user is logged in as a Wholesale Customer then a different email will be notified.

I've found how to change it when a new order is complete using the `woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order` hook but i can't find any hooks related to the failed or cancelled notifications.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'sv_conditional_email_recipient', 10, 2 );


function sv_conditional_email_recipient( $recipient, $order ) {

    // Bail on WC settings pages since the order object isn't yet set yet
    // Not sure why this is even a thing, but shikata ga nai
    $page = $_GET['page'] = isset( $_GET['page'] ) ? $_GET['page'] : '';
    if ( 'wc-settings' === $page ) {
        return $recipient; 
    }

    // just in case
    if ( ! $order instanceof WC_Order ) {
        return $recipient; 
    }


         if ( in_array( 'wholesale_customer', (array) $user->roles )  ) {
            $recipient .= ', shaun@example.com';
            return $recipient;
        }

    return $recipient;
}


add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'sv_conditional_email_recipient', 10, 2 );
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The hook you are already using is a composite hook: [**`woocommerce_email_recipient_{$this->id}`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Email.html#269), where `{$this->id}` is the `WC_Email` ID like `new_order`. So you can set any email ID instead to make it work for the desired email notification.

Below You have the 3 hooks for "New Order", "Cancelled Order" and "Failed Order" that you can use for the same hooked function.

In your function, I have removed some unnecessary code and completed the code to get the customer data *(the user roles)* related to the order:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'user_role_conditional_email_recipient', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_cancelled_order', 'user_role_conditional_email_recipient', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_failed_order', 'user_role_conditional_email_recipient', 10, 2 );
function user_role_conditional_email_recipient( $recipient, $order ) {
    if ( ! is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) return $recipient;

    // Get the customer ID
    $user_id = $order->get_user_id();

    // Get the user data
    $user_data = get_userdata( $user_id );

    // Adding an additional recipient for a custom user role
    if ( in_array( 'wholesale_customer', $user_data->roles )  )
        $recipient .= ', shaun@example.com';

    return $recipient;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works.

Comment: Hi Loic, that's worked! Thank you very much. And thank you for the tip about targeting individual email ID's :)

Comment: Hi Mate, just realised. $user_id should be $customer_id?

Comment: @Shaun … Yes sorry I have corrected my little errors, updating this answer… thanks